# S3 Policy : Trying to only allow specific users and resources and accidentaly blocked myself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an S3 Bucket that i want to restrict its access to only some specific users. I created a test account IAM : "test.access" and i put this policy on my bucket :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AuthorizeOnlySpecifiedUsers",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotPrincipal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/test.access"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-xxxxxx-dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-xxxxxx-dev/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now the problem is that the bucket is not accessible to anyone even the user test.access

What's going on with the policy ?

Thank you.

Comment: For every other user, deny statement will match and access will be denied, for user "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/test.access" , the deny statement doesn't match but the policy doesn't have an allow statement so it's rejected by the implicit deny, unless the user is in the same account and have the permission at the IAM level, it needs an allow statement as well. (if in different account)

Comment: That is not a valid S3 resource policy, the second statement is missing the action and the opening '{'.  Can you update the policy.

Comment: @JamesDean Yes you're right, the user was created in an another account and he's assuming a role to be able to access the bucket (he has "s3:*" in its policy).
What should be modified in that case ?

Comment: @WaltDe The second statement ? There is only one statement in my Policy ... And now i'm not able to edit the policy or anything else on this bucket

Comment: @user1297406 You will need root credentials or use the CLI to delete the bucket policy and start over.   Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040323/how-do-i-unlock-or-delete-an-aws-s3-bucket-that-inadvertently-locked-with-a-buck

Answer (score 0):

This policy should work (I haven't been able to test it yet).   A couple things to note

- Make sure to include yourself in the Deny NotPrincipal Policy
- If you don't want your users having full access to the bucket list the actions they need int eh Allow part.  Additional actions for yourself and other admins will be granted in the IAM User/Role polices

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AuthorizeOnlySpecifiedUsers",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "s3:*"
      ],
      "NotPrincipal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/test.access",
          "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxx:user/yourself"
        ]
      },
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-xxxxxx-dev",
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-xxxxxx-dev/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
        "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
        "s3:DeleteObject*",
        "s3:PutObject*",
        "s3:GetObject*",
        "s3:RestoreObject*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-xxxxxx-dev",
        "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket-xxxxxx-dev/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```